# How to force nodes in rows based on weight of incoming edges

Tags: graph, graphviz

I would like to get a configuration where nodes are placed in rows based on the "weight" of incoming rows. Not sure if "weight" is the right word, but in the following case,

```
a -> b
b -> c
c -> d
```

the weight of the incoming edge to d should be 3, because it's 3 edges leading to d from the root. Similarly all nodes that have no incoming edges should be placed at the top. I dont care about the lengths of edges, as long as the rows are correct.

Arbitrarily, I've found that nodes sometimes end up in different rows. E.g., if a node has no incoming edges, it has sometimes ended up in a row after the first.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: A topological sort will give you the nodes ordered by distance from the root.

Comment: @ravenspoint How do I sort topologically with graphviz?

Comment: Sort first, then force graphviz to place the nodes in the rows.  https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/pos/

Comment: Sorry how do I sort? Is there some easy way to do this for a graph with lots of nodes?

Comment: You could google topological sort.  Or look at the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOOP over root nodes ( those with no incoming edges )
   Do a Breadth First Search ( BFS ) from root
        Mark each node visited with distance from root
LOOP over nodes
   Add each node to the row where that has its depth == distance from root
```

If you are looking after the drawing in your own code

```
LOOP over rows
   Draw the node at the end of its row
LOOP over edges
   Draw edge between src and destination node
```

If you are using grahviz, then position the nodes using https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/pos/